# How can I disable FastCGI on a Windows IIS 6 server?

Tags: php, windows-server-2003, wordpress, fastcgi

We use WordPress for our company website and it has crashed for no discernible reason. It gives an error message like this:

```
FastCGI Error
The FastCGI Handler was unable to process the request.

Error Details:

    The FastCGI process has failed frequently recently. Try the request again in a while
    Error Number: -2147467259 (0x80004005).
    Error Description: Unspecified error

HTTP Error 500 - Server Error.
Internet Information Services (IIS)
```

After reading up, it seems that WordPress does not work well with FastCGI and doesn't need to be used with it. Would anyone kindly be able to tell me how to turn FastCGI's interaction with WordPress off?

Comment: I was under the impression that WordPress used PHP, and PHP on IIS needs FastCGI?

[http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php)

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same experience.  To disable FastCGI on my wordpress installations, I have done the following:

In the IIS manager, I created an App Pool for wordpress.  Then, under "Web Sites", browse to the folder containing your WordPress installation.  Right click on that folder, and select "Properties."

On the "Directory" tab, create an application.  Select the App Pool created for WordPress, and then click the "Configuration" button.  Remove any Wildcard application maps.  In the list of Application extensions, scroll down to ".php" and click "Edit...".  Set the executable path to wherever you installed PHP, with php-cgi.exe as the executable (e.g. c:\ProgramFiles\PHP5\php-cgi.exe).

Save, restart IIS, and it should work.

What I would like to know is how to completely disable fastcgi once it's been set up.

Comment: php-cgi.exe IS the FastCGI module - so what you did above is actually enabled it, not disabled it...